# Is it possible to find all values of $k$, like a function $k=f(m)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to find all values of $k$, like a function $k=f(m)$, such that

> $$\begin{cases} 81k-41\equiv 0 \mod{2^m} \\ \frac{81k-41}{2^m} \equiv 1 \mod 2 \end{cases}$$
>
> Here, $$\left\{ m,k \right\}\in \mathbb {Z^{+}}$$

I can found a random values: for example

$m=3,k=1$

$m=1,k=3...$

> My question is:
>
> Is it possible to find a general form for value of $m$ like a function $k=f(m)?$

If I express my problem with words, for example, $m=10$ and I want to find direct value ,what is value of $k?$

*In short, I want to make $k$ dependent on $m$ in general, like a function.*

Is it possible?

Comment: I assume the two $k$ are the same, $81k-41\equiv 1 \mod{2^{m+1}} \implies 81k-41\equiv 1 \mod{2^{m}}$

Comment: More succinctly $m$ is the $2$-adic valuation of $81k-41$.  I’m not sure that there is a way to calculate it that is more efficient on average than the already quite-fast “keep dividing by $2$ until you can’t”.  However there are very efficient ways to answer questions like “what are all the values of $k$ for which $m=100$?”.  Your question does not appear to be seeking this, but it is written in an unclear way.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, you are right..Could you edit the my problem for me so that is clearer?Thank you!

Comment: I fixed to be clearer as you said

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to the edited question.

Your equations mean that $81k-41=(2n+1)2^m$ for some integer $n\ge0$, or equivalently, $81k\equiv2^m+41 \mod{2^{m+1}}$.

Let $a$ be a modular multiplicative inverse of $81$ mod $2^{m+1}$, i.e., an integer such that $81a\equiv1\mod{2^{m+1}}$. (This can be computed using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). Alternatively, [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) gives $a\equiv81^{2^m-1}\mod{2^{m+1}}$ as an explicit solution, but this is relatively inefficient.) Then we have $k\equiv(2^m+41)a\mod{2^{m+1}}$. This gives all the solutions for $k$.

Comment: For example, $m=10$, What is $k$?

Comment: Using the extended Euclidean algorithm, you can get $177(81)-7(2^{11})=1$. Therefore, we can pick $a=177$. $k$ follows from the above formula.

Answer (score 0):

If $k=1$ and $m=3$ then $40\equiv 0 \mod 2$ but $40 \not\equiv 1 \mod 16$.

So, I don't know to what correspond your "random values", but certainly not to solutions of your system of equations.

In general, if $81k-41 \equiv 1 \mod 2^{m+1}$, then by definition of the modulo, we  have  $81k-41 \equiv 1 \mod 2^{m}$, and by properties of the modulo relation, $0\equiv 1 \mod 2^m$. Equivalently, this means that $2^m$ divides $1$. It can happen only if $m=0$.

In this case, the first equation is satisfied for all $k$, and the second one may be rewritten as $k\equiv 1 \mod 2$.

To sum up: if $k$ is odd, the equations of your system are not satisfied for any $m$.

If $k$ is even, the only solution of your equation is $m=0$.

Comment: I'm Sorry for mistakes now I fixed